# AutoMapper context values in AfterMap?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

i know you can do this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Foo, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(res => res.Context.Options.Items["Foo"])

Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(src, opt => opt.Items["Foo"] = "Bar");
```

but how do you access contextual data in AfterMap() ?

Comment: What do you mean saying contextual data? Can you give an example?

Comment: look at my example code, i can pass "options" with contextual data in a dictionary --> Items["Foo"] = someValue,  this allows me to pass contextual data when im converting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you can't. But that's an easy fix, open a GitHub issue and we'll add it in (for BeforeMap and AfterMap).

Comment: Did this ever get implemented? This would be tremendously useful for supporting multiple version of clients, ie: when you need to pass a request-specific "ClientVersion" which you may want to change the shape of the returned data after mapping. The MVC controllers would then need to pass this request-specific data to the mapper, which is otherwise unaware of request-specific data/headers/etc.

Comment: Thanks for implementing this (tested as of v6.1). AutoMapper is awesome!  =)